# boolean operation with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to use `pandas.groupby` in a particular way. Given a DataFrame with two boolean columns (call them `col1` and `col2`) and an id column, I want to add a column in the following way:

for every entry, if (`col2` is True) and  and (`col1` is True for any of the entries with the same id) then assign True. Otherwise False.

I have made a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,2,2,3,3],[False, False, False, False, False, False, True],[False, True, False, False, True ,True, False]]).transpose()
df.columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2']
```

gives the following `DataFrame`:

```
     id   col1   col2
0    0   False   False
1    1   False   True
2    1   False   False
3    2   False   False
4    2   False   True
5    3   False   True
6    3   True    False
```

According to the above rule, the following should column should be added:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
```

Any ideas on an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df.groupby('id').col1.transform('any') & df.col2

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 6):

This code will produce the output you requested:

```
df2 = df.merge(df.groupby('id')['col1'] # group on "id" and select 'col1'
                    .any()              # True if any items are True
                    .rename('cond2')    # name Series 'cond2'
                    .to_frame()         # make a dataframe for merging
                    .reset_index())     # reset_index to get id column back
print(df2.col2 & df2.cond2)             # True when 'col2' and 'cond2' are True
```